# JQuery script couldn't be executed in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Good day, What I'm trying to do is to create a html table in jsp and modify the table with JQuery script(i reused a old, working script). The problem is i have never used JQuery nor web programming before but i have managed to compile a working version of the jsp which can generate a table but i couldn't make the JQuery script to execute.

My Simplified JSP :

```
     <HEAD>      
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
     </HEAD>

     <body>

     <%
     out.println("<table>");
     out.println("<tr>");
     out.println("<td>"+val_feature+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+val_project+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+val_suiteID+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+val_suiteTitle+"</td>");
     ..............
     ..............
     ..............
     out.println("</tr>");
     out.println("</table>");
     %>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        console.clear();
        var table = $("table");
        var rows = table.find($("tr"));
        var colsLength = $(rows[0]).find($("td")).length;
        var removeLater = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<colsLength; i++){
            var startIndex = 0;
            var lastIndex = 0;
            var startText = $($(rows[0]).find("td")[i]).text();
            for(var j=1; j<rows.length; j++){
                var cRow =$(rows[j]);
                var cCol = $(cRow.find("td")[i]);
                var currentText = cCol.text();
                if(currentText==startText){
                    cCol.css("background","gray");
                    console.log(cCol);
                    removeLater.push(cCol);
                    lastIndex=j;
                }else{
                    var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
                    if(spanLength>=1){
                        console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
                        //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]))
                        $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
                    }
                    lastIndex = j;
                    startIndex = j;
                    startText = currentText;
                }

            }
            var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
                    if(spanLength>=1){
                        console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
                        //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]))
                        $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
                    }

        }

        for(var i in removeLater){
            $(removeLater[i]).remove();
        }


    </script>

     </body>
```

When i execute the page the table is not modified by the JQuery and IE keeps throwing error 'console' undefined. I don't know if these problem related but when i remove the console.clear(), it still doesn't execute the script and throw 'Object is expected' error at 2nd line of the script `var table = $("table");`
Thanks in advance. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: make sure the jquery is referenced correctly

Comment: in firefox or chrome console is there any error !
make sur jquery is loaded !
and try to make jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ .... your code here ...})`